# how to set Email domain alias on vestacp

Tags: email, dns, server

I'm installing my new server with Vesta CP and everything is working great!

Only one thing I can't figure out is how to add an email domain alias. For web it is pretty simple, just add an alias :)

But how to do it for email? I want `mydomain.org` to have the same emailaddresses (and mail accounts) as `mydomain.com`, so that `info@mydomain.org` will be delivered at `info@mydomain.com`

I've tried add email alias but it only allow add email alias for the same domain. Ex: `email_1@domain.com` alias to `email_2@domain.com`

I use cloudflare as DNS.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a cross domain alias. You need to add both domains, then on the domain which you want to forward from, create an account `info@domain.org` and put `info@domain.com` in the box that says "Forward to". Also make sure that "Do not store forwarded mail" is checked. That should accomplish what you're after.